# PHP replace only plain text

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5.3

Following PHP function replaces all Latin digits with Persian digits, But it also replaces all Latin digits of the attributes of HTML tags, that makes them not working anymore, I want to replace the digits of only plain text, Please help me if know how to do that, thank you.

```
public static function LatinToPersianDigits($html)
{
  $Latin= ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
  $Persian= ['۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹'];
  return str_replace($latin, $persian, $html);
}
```

Comment: This won't work. You are trying to forge metal with a screwdriver. you use a tool to work with strings and apply it to markup structures. Use a tool for markup structures: a DOM parser.

Comment: you can use this regex >([^<]*)<  to select anything between tags

Comment: @arkascha, I myself wanted to use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, But I was wondering if there is a way to do that without using extra packages which may reduce the speed of the loading pages.

Comment: @Amigo: Simple HTML DOM Parser isn't so simple (and is inefficient), using the build in DOMDocument class is better IMHO.

Comment: You'd have to use a much much more complex regular expression, since you'd have to reimplement quite a part of the logic inside the dom parser package as a regular language. How else do you want your replacement behave markup agnostic, if not by implementing that? That certainly will be _much_ less efficient that using an additional package.

Comment: @mohade, preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', LatinToPersianDigits(?), $html);

Comment: @Amigo: using a direct string approach as mohade suggested is only a bad idea since there are many traps to make this approach to fail.

Comment: With DOMXPath, you can easily extract all text nodes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, Yeah, I can extract the plain text easily, but my problem is that I don't know how to apply this function only on the plain text

Comment: i suggest to apply this function to data when you get it from database or anywhere else..and the regex and replace  match is  a complex little bit and not efficient

Comment: @arkascha, No I don't have any markup agnostic, only normal html tags and attributes

Comment: 1) build the dom tree using DOMDocument, 2) extract text nodes with DOMXPath, 3) translate digits using `strtr`, 4) replace the text nodes, 5) save the dom tree in a string.

Comment: HTML _is_ a form of markup. "Hyper text _markup_ language" (HTML)

Comment: @Amigo at first from where you are retrieve your data to print it on the page

Comment: I retrieve my data from MySQL, as CasimiretHippolyte, arkascha and you said using DOMDocument is the best way, but my more complex part is that maybe the plain text also contains English text, my code must be smart enough to not to traverse the digits of that English text!!

Comment: I have this problem because some of Persian fonts don't have a standard unicode they put Latin digits instead of Persian digits

Comment: you can use it like that echo LatinToPersianDigits($row['text']):;

Comment: @mohade, $row['text'] == html

Comment: why you save html entities in your database

Comment: @mohade, Because I use WYSIWYG HTML Editor.

Comment: be aware from xss  ...try @CasimiretHippolyte  answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example:

```
const TRANSDIGIT = [ '۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹' ];

public static function LatinToPersianDigits($html)
{
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new \DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?><div>' . $html . '</div>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $xp = new \DOMXPath($dom);
    $textNodeList = $xp->query('//text()');

    foreach($textNodeList as $textNode) {
        $textNode->parentNode->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode(strtr($textNode->nodeValue, self::TRANSDIGIT)), $textNode);
    }

    $result = '';

    foreach ($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $childNode) {
        $result .= $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

If you need something more smart to select specific parts of the text, you can always build a pattern (for `preg_replace_callback`) or a function to select these parts.

[demo](https://eval.in/655180)

Comment: Thank your answer I appreciate it, but It produce following gibberish:

Comment: @Amigo: What kind of gibberish? Could you show it in an eval.in demo?

Comment: you are awesome , I only added support for utf8 unicode and your code worked as well as a Swiss watch, Thank you for your help mate :)

Comment: @Amigo: if you add the xml declaration with the correct encoding it works.